# Firebase Javascript Send Multiple Endpoints

Tags: c#, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have asp .net application which is sends notification message to clients with firebase javascipt sdk.
We have 9000 users endpoints.
How can i send notification message to all users at once.

```
var message = {

to: 'endpoint',

notification: {
    title: message.title,
    body: message.information
}
```

Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

Sending messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging can be done by calling its HTTP endpoint. The process is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message).

If the messages should be available to all users of your app, you might consider having them subscribe to a specific topic and then [sending a message to that topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics).

If the message should be individually delivered to each user, you can [send a message to the individual devices](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_specific_devices). At the moment that means that you need to make 9000 calls to the API, but a [multicast feature is in the works](https://youtu.be/ltm9EWpV124?t=4m42s).